# C++ Windows Forms witout .net framework?

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio, winforms

Can I work with C++ WinForms for creating GUI app without having .net using visual studio? or I have to switch to another IDE? which IDE will be the best?

I want to get help working with windows forms witout using .net framework in my GUI app.

Comment: There is the MFC framework : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/creating-an-mfc-application?view=msvc-170. But really C# + WPF is far better for creating UI's on windows.

Comment: @PepijnKramer MFC framework has win forms?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve here? Why _wouldn't_ you want to use a free community license for Visual Studio to do [mixed mode programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/mixed-native-and-managed-assemblies) with C++/CLI and WinForms if that's what you need to write? And no, MFC doesn't "have" WinForms because it's the _native-unmanaged_ side of things. It's basically a wrapper (sometimes thin) for the raw Win32 API. WinForms is the _managed_ side of the mixed mode and C++/CLI is how one marshals from one side to the other. WinForms _is_ .NET no way around that.

Comment: @IVSoftware If I use the .net WinForms, it will need the user to install the .net framework on the system before running the application, this is why I want to have a pure C++ application which doesn't depends on any other third party framework.

Comment: .NET Framework 4.8 / 4.8.1 is part of the System, in more recent Windows Systems for sure. In older version of Windows (I mean Windows 7, mostly), it's also quite probable (~90%+) to find .NET Framework 4.8

Comment: No MFC doesn't have winforms like .Net does. But you can't have winforms without .Net. And you can ship your installer with a .Net redistributable installer if eeded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WinForms (`System.Windows.Forms`) is a managed namespace that relies on .NET and I don't see any help forthcoming when you say:

> I want to get help working with windows forms witout using .net framework in my GUI app.

What one *can* do is write an app using "Visual C++" using MFC and this will allow you to work with [Win32 common controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/individual-control-info) without .NET dependencies or managed code. So you'd have dialog, list, and text boxes and the like. It seems possible that you're saying "windows forms" when what you really want is "Visual C++".

Whether you want to write MFC or WinForms (or marshal between the two using [C++/CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/mixed-native-and-managed-assemblies)) they are both richly supported in Visual Studio and many individual developers qualify for a free community license for it.

Are you developing for Windows PCs? It would be rare to find an installation that doesn't already have .NET framework on it.

Answer (score 0):

.NET Framework 4.8 is installed by default on all recent Windows versions (and updated automatically via Windows Update), so it's allways available. And when you go with .NET 6.0+ you can build self-containing apps that do not need a separate installation of the runtime.

Of course, you can build GUI applications using MFC and VC++, but that typically also requires installation of a runtime, unless you limit yourself to very basic Windows features. But unless you are a very experienced C++ developer, the effort to work with this meanwhile really aged technology will be much higher than going with C#.

Besides: Most users will anyway expect an installer when they download an app, so installing runtimes will usually be just fine.